# How to bold a string within a string and variables

Tags: excel, vba

**Code**

Below is my Function:

```
Function InitialHeading(Optional ByVal Accrual As String, Optional ByVal Status As String, Optional ByVal Description As String, Optional ByVal RecipientAccount As String, Optional ByVal RecipientName As String, Optional ByVal AgreeType As String, Optional ByVal DateFrom As String, Optional ByVal DateTo As String) As String

    InitialHeading = "Accrual: " & Accrual & "    Agreement Status: " & Status & "    Date: " & DateFrom & " - " & DateTo & "    Description: " & Description & "    Rebate Recipient Details: Account - " & RecipientAccount & "    Name - " & RecipientName

End Function
```

**Problem**

I want all the non variables to be bold. I want variables Accrual & Status font colour red.

**Research**

I have done multiple sarches but the best I can get is setting the entire string ie. `InitialHeading` ALL bold or ALL red.

**Output**

In the below output the variable `Status = "Open"` and thus the word `Open` needs to be font = red:

**Accrual:** 123456    **Agreement Status:** Open      etc etc etc

Comment: You cannot format a string in a variable. That is not possible, you can only format it in a cell.

Comment: Thanks. Guess we can close this question then

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for the link. I tried all sorts of searching but never search for that specific search text. This will work nicely. Cheers!